# mobile application handling sensitive data

Tags: testing, mobile, browser, operating-system, financial

I was asked this question by a friend of mine and was wondering if anyone might have an answer to this.

Given you have a mobile application that handles sensitive data and financial transactions, 
and that the application must work on 25+ combinations of operating systems and 
browsers, across multiple locales and you are using an iterative development approach,
what overall test strategy would you apply to keep your regression test defect detection rate low?

Thanks in advance